# Open an existing Excel file and run a macro in that file through MS Project

Tags: excel, vba, ms-project

I want to open an Excel file named `Open_Yard_Scheduling_tool_V8.xlsm`, run a macro in the same Excel file named `formulcopy` and then copy the data from the Excel file and paste into MS Project file by writing a code in VBA in MS Project application.

I am able to open the Excel file and copy its data and paste it into the required project file but I'm not able to run the macro file in Excel through VBA in MS Project.

I am using the code mentioned below.

```
Sub ex_mac()   
    Dim xlApp As Object
    Dim xlWkb As Object

    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set xlWkb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\DHRUV.HEMIL.MANOJ\Documents\Open_Yard_Scheduling_tool_V8.xlsm")

    xlApp.Visible = True

    Application.Run ("'C:\Users\DHRUV.HEMIL.MANOJ\Documents\Open_Yard_Scheduling_tool_V8.xlsm'!formulcopy") 
End Sub
```

It is only opening the required Excel file but it is not able to run the macro in the same Excel file.

Comment: Instead of `Application.Run` try `xlApp.Run ("'Open_Yard_Scheduling_tool_V8.xlsm'!formulcopy")`

Comment: Put the macro into the workbook project under the `Workbook_Open` Event

Comment: @Damian This will also trigger the macro if the workbook is opened normally by hand which might not be the desired action.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I know, shouldn't he write the `formulcopy` directly to the workbook containing the code? Not the target file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that `Application.Run` refers to the MS Project application but you try to run code in the Excel application. Therefore you need to use `xlApp.Run` instead (which refers to the Excel applictation that you created with `Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")`:

```
xlApp.Run("'Open_Yard_Scheduling_tool_V8.xlsm'!formulcopy")
```

*Note that the full path is not needed here.*