# from MS Project and using vba, create buttons on an excel worksheet and launch a macro in excel by running an MS project macro to launch it

Tags: excel, vba, ms-project

reference article on StackOverflow upon which my question is based:

[Open an existing Excel file and run a macro in that file through MS Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56144122/open-an-existing-excel-file-and-run-a-macro-in-that-file-through-ms-project)

Using the above reference, I created a new module in Microsoft Project and inserted this routine:

```
     Sub sraTest()
        Dim xlApp As Object
        Dim xlWkb As Object

       Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
       Set xlWkb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\export\SRA-text.xlsm")
      xlApp.Visible = True
      xlApp.Run "'SRA-text.xlsm'!SRA_Run"
  End Sub
```

In excel, I loaded the following  code in the "ThisWorkbook" folder in Excel. The file was saved as C:\Export\SRA-text.xlsm.

```
   Option Explicit

   Sub SRA_Run()
   Dim i As Long
   'enter the row Number
      activesheet.cells(7+i,1) = 7+i 
      For i = 1 To 5

         AddButton "Sheet11", i
      Next i
  End Sub

  Public Sub AddButton(strSheetName As String, counter As Long)
     Dim btn As OLEObject
     Dim cLeft, cTop, cWidth, cHeight

     With Worksheets(strSheetName).Range("J" & (6 + counter))
            cLeft = .Left
            cTop = .Top
            cWidth = .Width
            cHeight = .Height
         End With
        With Worksheets(strSheetName)
            Set btn = .OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.commandbutton.1", Link:=True, _
            DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=cLeft, Top:=cTop, Width:=cWidth, _
            Height:=cHeight)
        End With
        btn.Object.Caption = ActiveSheet.Cells(6 + counter, 1) & "-iter-0"
        btnCaption = Left(strSheetName, 3) & counter
        btn.Name = Left(strSheetName, 3) & counter
        ActiveSheet.Cells(6 + counter, 11) = btn.Name


        With ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents( _
           ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(strSheetName).CodeName).CodeModule
          .InsertLines Line:=.CreateEventProc("Click", btn.Name) + 1, _
          String:=vbCrLf & _
          "MsgBox ""Hello world"""
       End With
  End Sub
```

Running the procedure from excel, the procedures runs exactly as one would expect.  However, when I  run the procedure from the Microsoft Project module, the system responds saying it cannot find the macro on excel or the macro does not exists. It does open the Excel file. The code to add the row number to column 1 on the excel worksheet is so I can eventually display a reference to an activity number on the button caption. The only variable in the excel macro is the sheet number in the code.  When finally applied, there will ALWAYS be the same sheet number ion the .xlsm excel file that will be search for existing OLE Objects and for every OLEObject found, will create a new button to cover the existing OLE Object and also create the Event Handler for that button to OPEN the OLEObject picture.

An inelegant solution to this would be to place a button on an invisible worksheet in this excel workbook as part of the .xlsm saved excel file, pre-loaded with a macro calling the SRA_Run procedure, which would also be loaded in the "ThisWorkbook" vba module. I could use DDE to do this to create a "click" event on the hidden worksheet's button to run the procedure. However, this is also not the preferred method I would choose.  Launching the excel macro from Microsoft Project should not be so difficult!

Is the reference topic at the start of this article only expected to work excel to excel, or should it also work MS Project to Excel?.

I have included the excel workbook with all code in it.  The code in the MS Project module is pretty straight forward, so I did not include it. I am using the MS Project macro code to test the excel code and to verify I can create buttons and event handlers specific to each button created.  I have entirely different procedures I am going to load into the excel macro-enabled workbook once this procedure is wroking.
I read all of the comments on the original posting but am unable to get this macro on the MS Project side to launch the Excel macro. Can you offer any suggestions that I can track down.  There is very little information on the internet on creating macros on one office application (MS Project) and have it launch a macro on another office application (Excel). This is the last obstacle I have to completing this project, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

I am using MS Project Pro 2019 and MS Office Excel 2019, version 2102 Build 13801.20266. The Version and Build apply to both Project and Excel.

Comment: In the Excel workbook, put the code in a regular code module: Insert > Module.

Comment: Thank you. Thank you. Thank you, BigBen. Works as I had hoped.